# LSTM for predicting next n time steps with multiple input features

Tags: python, tensorflow, time-series, lstm

I am kind of stuck with my model at the moment.

I have time series data which looks like this:

```
Date        var1         var2        var3       var4          var5        var6
2015-01-02  0.008345    0.161392    0.128982    0.832584    0.006930    79.530273
2015-01-05  0.008374    0.161392    0.128949    0.841107    0.007020    90.269531
...
2021-01-08  0.008390    0.161199    0.128967    0.850629    0.007100    55.429688
```

I want to use the last 3 timesteps of **all** of the variables to predict the next 2 timesteps of var6. So far so good. I created my data such that it looks like this:

```
var1(t-3)       var2(t-3)   var3(t-3)      ....                                                                                                                                                                                         var6(t+1)
3   0.505040    0.974723    0.956856    0.120007    0.267241    0.153212    0.513697    0.974723    0.936600    0.154792    0.297082    0.141920    0.528732    0.971972    0.961168    0.155416    0.313660    0.120967    0.116883    0.150163
4   0.513697    0.974723    0.936600    0.154792    0.297082    0.141920    0.528732    0.971972    0.961168    0.155416    0.313660    0.120967    0.528856    0.973194    0.953739    0.179536    0.323607    0.116883    0.150163    0.150764
5   0.528732    0.971972    0.961168    0.155416    0.313660    0.120967    0.528856    0.973194    0.953739    0.179536    0.323607    0.116883    0.518223    0.967189    0.947523    0.193654    0.323607    0.150163    0.150764    0.145170
```

```
# split into input and outputs
n_out = 2
n_in = 3

train_X, train_y = values_train[:, :-n_out], values_train[:, -n_out:]
test_X, test_y = values_test[:, :-n_out], values_test[:, -n_out:]

# reshape input to be 3D [samples, timesteps, num_features]

train_X = train_X.reshape((train_X.shape[0], n_in, 6))
test_X = test_X.reshape((test_X.shape[0], n_in, 6))
print(train_X.shape, train_y.shape, test_X.shape, test_y.shape)
# num samples, num time steps, num features
(1825, 3, 6) (1825, 2) (412, 3, 6) (412, 2)
```

Which also works to train the following model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(2))
```

Predicting samples from my test set however does yield results which indicate something went wrong in the training to me: The two lines are two different samples which have been predicted. I don't understand why the graphs are synchronous. Given the data they should be running behind each other, since the two samples to be predicted are just shifted by one timestep. Is there something wrong with my architecture; it looks like a systematic error to me since this looks the same for all samples in the test set.

Note: The length is 7 here, because I tried to predict the next seven time steps here, but it doesn't matter how long the output sequence is, the result is still the same
[image]